Hide iframe in the absence of its stylesheet
I have an iframe with the following element in its header
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/web/assets/report.min.css">

The problem is that this style sheet takes more time to load than the iframe. Because of that, the iframe would show without styling for 2 seconds or so.
What I want to do is to hide the iframe and only show it if this style sheet has fully loaded. How can I do this? Can I maybe listen to the url /web/assets/report.min.css and once it returns status code of 200 I can show the iframe?

You could make the webpage, that is contained in the iframe, invisible. For instance with:
<body style="display: none;">

And then add to the stylesheet:
body {
  display: initial !important;
}

to make the content visible when the stylesheet has loaded. I haven't tested this in practice, but I think it should work.

It worked, thanks a lot
